# Не получается найти обратную матрицу ковариации

Tags: java, матрицы

***Есть такая ковариационная матрица, размера 5 на 5:***

```
 5.86   -3.22    8.86   -0.32    76.88
-3.23    1.78   -4.88    0.18   -42.38
 8.86   -4.88   13.4    -0.48   116.3
-0.32    0.18   -0.48    0.02    -4.17
76.88  -42.38  116.3    -4.17  1009.06
```

**Пытаюсь от нее найти обратную, компилятор выдает ошибку:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Matrix is singular.

at Jama.LUDecomposition.solve(LUDecomposition.java:282)
at Jama.Matrix.solve(Matrix.java:815)
at Jama.Matrix.inverse(Matrix.java:833)
at com.lab3.UtilPassenger.getMetricsMahalanobis(UtilPassenger.java:138)
at testLab3.MetricClassifyTest.mainTest(MetricClassifyTest.java:79)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

**Подскажите, что делать?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290459/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-runtimeexception-matrix-is-singular?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Tsyklop понял. тогда такой вопрос . есть 2 величины x и y , размера 5. как найти обратную ковариационную матрицу от этих 2 величин?

Comment: А чему у вас равен детерминант? В ответе Tsyklop нормально написано, что матрица должна иметь не нулевой детерминант.

Comment: Так же там сказано, что одна строка не должна быть пропорциональна другой. это условие у вас нарушено.

Comment: 0. получается.
Матрицу ковариации нахожу для формулы расстояния Махаланобиса. у меня есть 2 величины - первая x и y как найти тогда обратную матрицу ковариации?